# Retrieving properties from Relationship (Hyperledger Composer)

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Refer to the following definitions (I know the relationship in the Address doesn't really make rational sense, but I'm using this as a hypothetical example):

```
concept Address {
  o String city optional
  o String country
  o String street optional
  o String zip optional
  --> Grower grower_temp optional
}

abstract participant Business identified by email {
  o String email
  o Address address
  o Double accountBalance
}

participant Importer extends Business {
}

participant Grower extends Business {
}
```

We create an importer:

```
 var importer2 = factory.newResource(NS, 'Importer', 'importer_cold_storage@email.com');
    var importerAddress2 = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Address');
    importerAddress2.country = 'Singapore';
    importerAddress2.grower_temp = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Grower', 'grower_banana@email.com');
    importer2.address = importerAddress2;
    importer2.accountBalance = 0;
```

How do I retrieve the properties of importer2.address.grower_temp?

e.g. **importer2.address.grower_temp.country** always result in "undefined". **importer2.address.grower_temp.getIdentifier()** runs successfully (i.e. result is **grower_banana@email.com**)

Answer (score 0):

so the answer is you will get the country by referencing it using:

`importer2.address.country` using the example below:

```
var importer = factory.newResource(NS, 'Importer', 'farmerjoe@email.com');
var importerAddress = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Address');
importerAddress.country = 'Singapore';
importerAddress.grower_temp = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Grower', 'grower_banana@email.com');
importer.address = importerAddress;
console.log('address is: ' + importer.address.country); // access it
importer.accountBalance = 0;
```

For your own purposes - you can print the results via console.log in your code.

I can see why getIdentifier() would work, because you set up a relationship and that uses the ID field.